# Float only displaying zeros (C)

Tags: c, floating-point

I am very very new to programming, so be easy on me.

As part of an assignment for a course, I need to use a float variable.
 However, I can't get it to work.

Below is an extract from my code (the rest is not relevant).

```
main()
{
    int x = 37.5;
    printf("%f",x);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, (BTW I'm using code::blocks) it just prints `0.000000`.

What is going wrong here? Shouldn't it work?

It works if I replace the %f with %d (well kinda, it truncates the decimal point).
I'm at a complete loss, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: why not `float x = 37.5;`?

Comment: Please edit your post to tag it with your programming language, it helps more people to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote `int x = 37.5;` The C compiler has an almost absolute confidence in programmer. You say x should be an int : it is, you initialize it to 37.5 : compiler does its best and take the int value of 37.5 which is 37.

If you want x to be a float, declare it as float :

```
float x = 37.5;
```

Note: After posting this answer, I realize that Gosu already gave it in a comment so credit should go to him.